# QMap::clear() crash

Tags: c++, linux, qt4, qmap

I'm running Qt-4.8.6 on Linux i686

I have a

```
QMap<quint32, QTreeWidgetItem *> mymap;
```

and when I simply call

```
mymap.clear();
```

the program crashes with stacktrace

```
...
#7  <signal handler called>
#8  0x0806f50c in QBasicAtomicInt::deref (this=0x34) at /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.6/include/QtCore/qatomic_i386.h:110
#9  0xa968c452 in QMap<unsigned int, QTreeWidgetItem*>::operator= (this=0xc53c51c, other=@0xbfa04b28)
at /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.6/include/QtCore/qmap.h:412
#10 0xa968c4d1 in QMap<unsigned int, QTreeWidgetItem*>::clear (this=0xc53c51c)
at /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.6/include/QtCore/qmap.h:424
...
```

Sorry I can't paste full stacktrace/code cuz I don't own the code.

This problem **doesn't happen every time**, or I should say it happens very rarely, but it did happen. I googled but only found things like "reinstall Qt", "use same compiler", etc.

Is there anything else I can do?

**EDIT**

I can paste some related Qt source code if that helps

```
// qmap.h
template <class Key, class T>
Q_INLINE_TEMPLATE void QMap<Key, T>::clear()
{
    *this = QMap<Key, T>();
}

template <class Key, class T>
Q_INLINE_TEMPLATE QMap<Key, T> &QMap<Key, T>::operator=(const QMap<Key, T> &other)
{
    if (d != other.d) {
        QMapData* o = other.d;
        o->ref.ref();
        if (!d->ref.deref())
            freeData(d);
        d = o;
        if (!d->sharable)
            detach_helper();
    }
    return *this;
}

// qatomic_i386.h
inline bool QBasicAtomicInt::deref()
{
    unsigned char ret;
    asm volatile("lock\n"
                 "decl %0\n"
                 "setne %1"
                 : "=m" (_q_value), "=qm" (ret)
                 : "m" (_q_value)
                 : "memory");
    return ret != 0;
}
```

Comment: Without an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) there is not much we can do to help.
Use a debugger and check where the code crashes exactly.

Comment: If it doesn't happen every time, you have something undefined in your code. The `this=0x34` suggests that there is a null pointer somewhere. That there is any kind of problem with `clear` suggests that the map itself has become corrupted somehow.

Comment: The two lines posted do not crash so in actual code the map itself is either already destroyed or corrupted by something.

Comment: @molbdnilo You're right, thanks for correcting me.